# gzip multiple files in python

Tags: python, file-io, gzip

I have to compress a lot of XML files into and split them by the data in the file name, just for clarification's sake, there is a parser which collects information from XML file and then moves it to a backup folder. My code needs to gzip it according to the date in the filename and group those files in a compressed .gz file.

Please find the code bellow:

```
import os
import re
import gzip
import shutil
import sys
import time    
#
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
logfile = 'D:\\Coleta\\log_compactador_xml_tar'+timestr+'.log'
ptm_dir = "D:\\PTM\\monitored_programs\\"
count_files_mdc = 0
count_files_3gpp = 0
count_tar = 0

#
for subdir, dir, files in os.walk(ptm_dir):
    for file in files:
        path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        try:
            backup_files_dir = path.split(sep='\\')[4]
            parser_id = path.split(sep='\\')[3]
            if re.match('backup_files_*', backup_files_dir):
                if file.endswith('xml'):
                    # print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), path)
                    data_arq = file[1:14]
                    if parser_id in ('parser-924'):
                        gzip_filename_mdc = os.path.join(subdir,'E4G_PM_MDC_IP51_'+timestr+'_'+data_arq)
                        with open(path, 'r')as f_in, gzip.open(gzip_filename_mdc + ".gz", 'at') as f_out_mdc:
                            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out_mdc)
                            count_files_mdc += 1
                            f_out_mdc.close()
                            f_in.close()
                            print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "Compressing file MDC: ",path)
                            os.remove(path)

        except PermissionError:
             print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "Permission error on file:", fullpath, file=logfile)
                    pass
        except IndexError:
            print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "IndexError: ", path, file=logfile)
        pass
```

As long as I seem it creates a stream of data, then compress and write it to a new file with the specified filename. However,  instead of grouping each XML file independently inside a ".gz" file, it does creates inside the "gzip" file, a big file (big stream of data?) with the same name of the output "gzip" file,  but without any extension. After the files are totally compressed, it's not possible to uncompress the big file generated inside the "gzip" output file. Does someone know where is the problem with my code?

PS: I have edited the code for readability purposes.

Comment: breaking your code up into smaller functions would help... Are you trying to create one gzip file containing a lot of other files?

Comment: Please fix your indentation, too.

Comment: You could probably use basic debugging techniques to work this out for yourself: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254094/question-that-can-be-solved-using-basic-debugging

Comment: @Harvey Exactly, I need to create one gzip file containing all of the XML files caught by the conditions in the algorithm. About the indentation, for me it shows the correct indentation, could you please evaluate what is wrong, so I can correct it asap.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ Tom Dalton, I have made a lot of troubleshooting already, but it took me nowhere until now, however, I will check the link to see if I missing something. Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: Look at the indentation right after `for file in files:`. Also, gzip only compresses one file. If you want multiple, you'll have to tar them first.

Comment: @ Harvey Thank you, was suspecting that this function of gzip lib had no support for multiple files, I am checking the other functions, if I get to find a workaround I will post here, thanks for your time and replies.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether the solution is still needed, but I will just leave it here for anyone who faces the same issue.
There is a way to create a gzip archive in python using tarfile, the code is quite simple:

```py
with tarfile.open(filename, mode="w:gz") as archive:
    archive.add(name=name_of_file_to_add, recursive=True)
```

in this case `name_of_file_to_add` can be a directory, in which case tarfile will add it recursively with all its contents. Obviously you will need to import the `tarfile` module.
If you need to add files without a directory a simple `for` with calls to `add` will do (`recursive` flag is not required in this case).